# Input not clickable next to span

Tags: css

I have successfully aligned a button to the right of a input. I am now experiencing a problem where the input is not clickable.

I have tried setting z-index for the input to a high number.

Can anyone help to figure out why the input isn't clickable?

```css
.input-add {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
}
.input-add > input {
  width: 90%;
  float: left;
}
input-add .audio-input-group {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 34px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-add">
  <input value="Test" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Main Artist">
  <span class="audio-input-group">
     <button class="btn-icon icon audio-icon-add" style="height:40px;"></button>
     </span>
</div>
```

Comment: there is no issue with your code whatsoever. care to add more details?

Comment: What do you mean by input not clickable ? The button ? You need to add some text between <button></button> to extend it, but you can already click on it. And we can click and type ttext in the input

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you need?

```css
.input-add {
  height: 40px;
}

.input-add > input {
  width: calc(100% - 55px);
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
}

.input-add .audio-input-group {
  font-size: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.input-add .audio-input-group > button.btn-icon {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="input-add">
  <input value="Test" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Main Artist">
  <span class="audio-input-group">
        <button class="btn-icon icon audio-icon-add">Test</button>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: The display:inline was the culprit. Sill dont understand . why

Comment: Hi, I don't think you may want to use display:inline for this DIV tag when you want to use it as a container of other elements. Take a look at this example http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_display&preval=inline